# How to create a 'fill in the blanks' form in Django

Tags: django, forms

I want to create a 'fill in the blanks' type of quiz in Django.

Example question is "Place your answers __ and __."

So basically, I want an output that would replace "__" fields with input fields.

Also, I want the input fields to have the same 'name'. Example:

```
<input id="id_1" type="text" name="blank[]" />
<input id="id_2" type="text" name="blank[]" />
```

The number of blank fields is(may be) infinite. How to go about it using django.forms?

Thank you.

Comment: will you know how many blanks you need at form instantiation time?

Comment: Use formsets: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: The number of blank fields is unknown. It depends on the number of "__" of the given question. Looking into formsets now, and see how can I use them. Thanks!

Comment: Basically, you create a form of one field. Then, using formsets, you can create as many new forms (one for each blank) as you like on the client side, and Django will instantiate a form instance for each on the server side after submit. Then you can just loop through the formset and do whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of fields on which you need to render quiz, as i understand.
So with list looking like this:

```
questions = (
  ('Place your 1 answers %s and %s.', ('field_1_1', 'field_2_2')),
  ('Place your 2 answers %s and %s.', ('field_2_1', 'field_2_2')),
)
```

You can create form for every field like this:

```
class QuizzForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QuizzForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for question in questions:
            for field in question[1]:
                self.fields[field] = forms.ChoiceField()
```

And access fields after post similiar to this:

```
if form.is_valid():
    for question in questions:
        for field in question[1]:
            answer = form.cleanded_data.get(field)
```